# Archiving files according to date in file name. Powershell script

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem, compress-archive

I am trying to make simple powershell script that is archiving files coming in daily. Every file has date at the beggining of its name, for example: `20211220_Something.csv, 20211220_SomethingElse.txt, 20211219_Something.csv, 20211219_SomethingElse.txt` etc...

I would like to make script that collects all files with extensions (*.txt, *.csv, *.xslx) from specifict directories which are:

`\\Main\Files` and `\\Main\Files\SecondaryFiles`

and archives all files with above extensions to for example `\\Main\Files\archive\2021\12\20.12.zip`

where 2021, 12 and 20.12 are elements of date provided in file name prefix. Inside 20.12.zip we have all files from `\\Main\Files` with directory named "SecondaryFiles" in which theres all files from the `\\Main\Files\SecondaryFiles`. After archiving i would like to delete all the files that i just zipped.

Right now i have this piece of code which loop through all files in the `\Main\` dir and extracts date prefix. I have tried using [Datetime]::parseexact() method but it doesnt work since my loop returns whole path. Anybody has any idea how to approach this?

```
$Date = Get-Date
$Day = $Date.Day
$Month = Date.Month
$Year = $Date.Year
$directoryPath = "\\Main\Files\archive'"+$Year+"\"+$Month
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\Main\Files" -Include *.txt, *.csv, *.xlsx -Recurse
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++){
$temp = $files[$i].FullName.split("_")[1]
}

if(!Test-Path -path $directoryPath){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPath
}

Compress-Archive -Path "\\Main\Files", "\\Main\Files\*.txt", "\\Main\Files\*.csv", "\\Main\Files\*.xlsx", "\\Main\Files\SecondaryFiles\*.txt", "\\Main\Files\SecondaryFiles\*.csv", "\\Main\Files\SecondaryFiles\*.xlsx" -Update -DestinationPath "\\Main\Files\archive\$Year\$Month\$Day.$Month.zip"
```

Then i am removing items from the original directory.

Also one thing worth mentioning is that I cant be sure if folder contains only files from todays date. So script should work fine when theres files from like all week lets say `20211214` till `20211220`.

So again i would like to Compress-Archive files like i did above but instead todays date the path would contain extracted date from file name prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to group all files having the same date prefix together and use that to create the output subdirectories, the final .zip file and also to remove the original files after zipping.

```
$sourcePath  = '\\Main\Files'
$destination = '\\Main\Files\archive'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Include '*.txt', '*.csv', '*.xlsx' -Recurse |
# select only files that start with 8 digits followed by an underscore
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^\d{8}_' } |
# group the files on the date part and loop trhough these groups
Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Substring(0,8) } | ForEach-Object {
    # split the date part into variables. Automatic variable $_ represents one Group, 
    # so we can take that group's Name to split into date parts 
    $year, $month, $day = $_.Name -split '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})' -ne ''
    # construct the target folder path for the zip file
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ('{0}\{1}' -f $year, $month)
    # create the new sub directory if it does not yet exist
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    # create the full path and filename for the zip file
    $zip = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath ('{0}.{1}.zip' -f $day, $month)
    # compress the files in the group  
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group.FullName -DestinationPath $zip -Update

    # here is where you can delete the original files after zipping
    $_.Group | Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
```

Note I have added switch `-WhatIf` to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet. This is a safety switch, so you are not actually deleting anything yet. The cmdlet now only displays what *would* be deleted. Once you are happy with this output, remove that `-WhatIf` switch so the files are deleted.